# Custom fields / subject fields from Highrise API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, highrise, 37-signals

I'm looking for a way to modify the values of [Custom fields](https://github.com/37signals/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/data_reference.md#custom-fields) (called `subject_fields` in the Highrise API somewhat confusingly).

The [Ruby wrapper](https://github.com/37signals/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/data_reference.md#custom-fields) 37signals recommends [does not support](https://github.com/tapajos/highrise/issues/18) these custom fields.

I found a [fork](https://github.com/numbata/highrise) that has been updated more recently and I've been able to get sort of working:

```
p = Highrise::Person.find_all_across_pages(:params => {:name => "John"}).last
print p.name # outputs, John Smith, which is what I want.
```

I have a custom field called "Measurements".

This works:

```
p.subject_data_hash # outputs {"measurements"=>"5 feet"}
```

However, when I try to access only this value with `p.field("Measurements")` (I also tried "measurements", I get `<Highrise::SubjectData:0x007fb059b6be10>`, with none of the [`@attributes`](https://github.com/numbata/highrise#highrise-custom-fields---read-and-write-called-subject_datas-in-the-highrise-api) that contain the data I'm looking for.

Needless to say, I can't modify the values if I can't access them.

How can I access and modify the values of custom fields in Ruby with the Highrise API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value:

```
 p.field("measurements").value
```

To set the value:

```
 p.set_field_value("measurements", "5 feet")
 p.save
```